# Update service MongoDB failed

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I'm trying to update my `mongodb-2` service with

`cf update-service $serviceInstance -p $newPlan`

But I get :

> **FAILED**
>
> Server error, status code: 400, error code: 110004, message: The service does not support changing plans.

Does that mean that `mongodb-2` plan can never be changed ? Or am I supposed to unbind applications before changing plan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cf update-service` is not supported by any of Swisscom services. You need to do this manually at the moment. Swisscom is working on `cf update-service` feature. Please subscribe to the newsletter to know when the feature is in production.

- dump data `mongodump` of old service instance
- create new service instance with other plan
- restore `mongorestore` data to new service instance
- delete old service instance

Detailed guide with `cf ssh`tunnel [here](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/migrate-mongodb-to-kubernetes-based-mongodb.html).

Comment: Okay. Where do I subscribe to this newsletter ?

Comment: @QuentinHerzig https://swisscom.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=6d3304d634e2c78b4e37ebc19&id=dda6a7f0cc